# ¿Cómo agregar una fila nueva arriba de las filas ya existentes con openpyxl?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, openpyxl

**Creacion de lista de tuplas**

```
datos = [("USA", 46, 12, 5),
        ("China", 38, 20, 7),
        ("UK", 29, 7, 7),
        ("Russia", 22, 10, 9),
        ("South Korea", 13, 3, 2),
        ("Germany", 11, 7, 4)]
```

**Creacion de variable para manejar hoja seleccionada**

```
hoja_tres = archivo_excel["Olimpiadas"]
```

**Iteracion sobre cada fila de la hoja**

```
for dato in datos:
    hoja_tres.append (dato)
archivo_excel.save ("02_Excel_data.xlsx")
```

**Movemos rango de celdas una fila hacia abajo**

```
hoja_tres.move_range ('A1:D7', rows = 1)

cabecera = [("Pais", "Oros", "Platas", "Bronces")]
```

**Objetivo**

Entonces quiero agregar la variable cabecera en la fila 1 que acabo de dejar libre. Pero con el metodo append me lo agrega al final de todas las filas

Answer (score 0):

Para resolverlo puedes hacer uso de una función que se aplica a listas: `insert(posicion, elemento)`. [Más información.](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_insert.asp)

**Ejemplo sencillo**:

0 es la posicion y 1 el elemento a añadir

```
lista = [2, 3]
lista.insert(0, 1)
print(lista)
```

El resultado es:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

**Código que resuelve lo que preguntas**:

```
datos = [("USA", 46, 12, 5), ("China", 38, 20, 7), ("UK", 29, 7, 7), ("Russia", 22, 10, 9), ("South Korea", 13, 3, 2), ("Germany", 11, 7, 4)]
cabecera = [("Pais", "Oros", "Platas", "Bronces")]
datos.insert(0, cabecera)
```

El resultado es:

```
[[('Pais', 'Oros', 'Platas', 'Bronces')], ('USA', 46, 12, 5), ('China', 38, 20, 7), ('UK', 29, 7, 7), ('Russia', 22, 10, 9), ('South Korea', 13, 3, 2), ('Germany', 11, 7, 4)]
```

**Código mejorado**:

Si quieres eliminar esos corchetes, [], que sobran:

```
datos = [("USA", 46, 12, 5), ("China", 38, 20, 7), ("UK", 29, 7, 7), ("Russia", 22, 10, 9), ("South Korea", 13, 3, 2), ("Germany", 11, 7, 4)]
cabecera = [("Pais", "Oros", "Platas", "Bronces")]
datos.insert(0, cabecera[0])
```

El resultado es:

```
[('Pais', 'Oros', 'Platas', 'Bronces'), ('USA', 46, 12, 5), ('China', 38, 20, 7), ('UK', 29, 7, 7), ('Russia', 22, 10, 9), ('South Korea', 13, 3, 2), ('Germany', 11, 7, 4)]
```

Comment: Claro la función insert me permite añadir un elemento a la posición de una lista deseada pero lo que desea hacer es: luego de que muevo el rango de datos, una fila abajo todos, queda la primera fila del excel libre y ahí quiero meter la variable cabecera.

Comment: Es lo que he hecho: insertar la variable cabecera en la primera fila

Comment: pero eso la inserta en la variable datos no? Yo necesito solo insertar la variable en la fila vacía. Ya que si realizo el insert en la variable datos luego necesito hacer append para que inserte la nueva variable pero la funcion append solo trabaja al final de todo los datos

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es meter tu nueva lista con append y después mover esa fila a la posición que quieras:

```
cabecera = hoja_tres.append(["Pais", "Oros", "Platas", "Bronces"])
hoja_tres.move_range("A7:D7", rows=-6, cols=0)
```